# What changes should I make to make my output return True of False based on the current state on the board?

Tags: python, list, error-handling

So I'm trying to create an easy version of t2048, and so I'm trying to start by finding whether **any moves are possible or not based on the current board**, and I have a function `ispossible(board: Board)` that returns whether this is True or False

In case you don't know what 2048 mean, this is what the game is... https://play2048.co/

**I'm not trying to recreate the entire game, I'm just trying to make a simple version of this that works.**

```
def ispossible(board: Board)
    for i in range(0, board):
        for j in range(1, board):
            if [i][j - 1] == 0 and [i][j] > 0:
                return True
            elif ([i][j - 1] == [i][j]) and [i][j - 1] != 0:
                return True
    return False
```

However, this doesn't work at all as I get an 'Error' when I put this as an input

```
print(ispossible([4,3,2,2],[2,2,8,16], [16,4,4,4], [4,4,4,4]))
```

What should I change to make sure this works??

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You probably want `for i in range(0, len(board))` as the range function takes integers, not lists. Alternatively, it may be simpler and more intuitive to simply use `for row in board` and iterate over the values directly instead of indexing them.

Comment: Your function only takes 1 argument, but you're passing 4 lists. I think you meant to put all of them into another list.

Comment: try `print(ispossible([[4,3,2,2],[2,2,8,16], [16,4,4,4], [4,4,4,4]]))`

Comment: @HarshaBiyani I tried it and it says index: list out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments to the question say, you should first pass in a single list of lists as your `Board`. Another issue with your example code is that you're not indexing into the `board` variable. Instead, the code is creating a size 1 list with `i` as the only element and then accessing the `j-1`th index. You probably meant to do something like `board[i][j - 1]` instead of `[i][j - 1]`. The same goes for your other list accesses.

Comment: so basically infront of every [i], I should write board?

Comment: yep, because currently `[i]` just means a list like `[0]` on the first iteration of the outer loop. `board[i]` would mean the ith row of `board`